# shell - replace string with incrementing value

Tags: shell, awk

I have this String:

```
"a | a | a | a | a | a | a | a"
```

and I want to replace every " | " with an incrementing value like so:

```
"a0a1a2a3a4a5a6a"
```

I know I can use gsub to replace strings:

```
> echo "a | a | a | a | a | a | a | a" | awk '{gsub(/\ \|\ /, ++i)}1'
a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a
```

But it seems gsub only increments after each newline, so my solution for now would be first putting a newline after each " | ", then using gsub and deleting the newlines again:

```
> echo "a | a | a | a | a | a | a | a" | awk '{gsub(/\ \|\ /, " | \n")}1' | awk '{gsub(/\ \|\ /, ++i)}1' | tr -d '\n'
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a
```

Which is honestly just disgusting...

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
s="a | a | a | a | a | a | a | a"

awk -F ' *\\| *' -v OFS="" '{s=""; for(i=1; i<NF; i++) s = s $i i-1; print s $i}' <<< "$s"

a0a1a2a3a4a5a6a
```

- `-F ' *\\| *'` will sets `|` surrounded by optional spaces as input field separator.
- `for` loop just goes through each field and appends field incrementing position after each field.

Answer (score 10):

If `perl` is okay:

```
$ echo 'a | a | a | a | a | a | a | a' | perl -pe 's/ *\| */$i++/ge'
a0a1a2a3a4a5a6a
```

- `*\| *` match `|` surrounded by zero or more spaces
- `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- `$i++` use value of `$i` and increment (default value `0`)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `awk`

```
echo "a | a | a | a | a | a | a | a" | 
awk -v RS="[ ]+[|][ ]+" '{printf "%s%s",(f?NR-2:""),$0; f=1}'
```

you get,

```
a0a1a2a3a4a5a6a
```

Answer (score 0):

If using just `sh` is an option, then perhaps substitute until a fixed point is reached:

```
s=$1  # first argument passed to script, "a | a | a |..."

n=0
while true
do
    prev=$s
    s=${s%" | a"}
    test "$s" = "$prev" && break
    result=$result${n}"a"
    n=$((n + 1))
done
echo $s$result
```

If this program lives in script file `digits.sh`,

```
$ sh digits.sh "a | a | a | a | a | a | a | a"
a0a1a2a3a4a5a6a
$
```